# Javascript - Regular expression for a first name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the right regular expression that will match a just a first name.

The first letter has to be a capital letter, followed by at least one lowercase letter.

I have tried `(!fname.match(/^[A-Z]{1,}\[a-z]{1,}$/))` but this doesn't seem to work.

I appreciate the help!

names that would match:
"Jack"
"Li"
"Ku"

Comment: So, you define the first name as *"a character sequence starting with a capital letter, followed by a variable number of lowercase letters"*? If not, then you have to provide some more explanation.

Comment: You're really unlikely to get this right. Consider the first names "José" and "LaVaughn" for example.

Comment: You commented on the now deleted answer *"This is not working :\"*. For what expression is it not working? We cannot help you if we don't know what's wrong. You get better help you give us as much (relevant) information as possible.

Comment: i changed the question to make it more comprehensive

Comment: You still haven't told why @VisioN's answer (which should be undeleted btw) doesn't work. AFAICT there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Juhana I've undeleted it but yet it doesn't support names, which Michael have provided.

Comment: And yes, I do hope this is not used to validate form fields. In addition to "José" and "LaVaughn", what about "Mary-Ann" or "Billy Bob"?

Comment: @VisioN and Michael: It doesn't work in real world but it does fit the OP's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test("Jack");
```

Technically set `[A-Z]` matches *one* capital letter, while `[a-z]+` matches *one or more* small letter(s) after the capital. Note that the following expression will not match names like `"José"` and `"LaVaughn"` as was mentioned by [@Michael Geary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806839/javascript-regular-expression-for-a-first-name/#comment22480059_15806877) in the comments.

Comment: What about `/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test("José");` or `/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test("LaVaughn");`? Oops... :-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary JavaScript doesn't like Unicode in regular expressions. True.

Comment: @user1871195 Could you specify what exactly doesn't work? The provided expression *should* match exactly the names of format you've described.